# SSH Tunneling with Android; Not working;

Tags: ssh

I have a rooted Galaxy S4.

I'm trying to establish an SSH tunnel so I can access mysql from my phone.

I've tried using multiple SSH apps to tunnel but I can never get any of my tunnels to work.

I think I'm doing something wrong, I would appreciated help.

Here is the command equivalent of the tunnel I'm trying to setup for mysql access.

```
ssh -L 1234:[mysql adress]:3306 [my ssh user]@[my domain name].com

Where [mysql adress] is the same address I use in php to connect to,
[my ssh user] is the username I use to login into ssh and ftp,
[my domain name] is the domain name I have and the one I use for ssh and ftp.
```

After that I would try to connect to mysql by connecting to

```
[my domain name].com:1234
```

and it would time out while waiting for response.

I've tried using different tunnels to test, but I can't get any of them to work.

I've tried to tunnel to the website http

```
ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:80 [my ssh user]@[my domain name].com
```

And it just hangs when I try to load

```
[my domain name].com:1234
```

in the browser.

I've also tried to tunnel to the website FTP server

```
ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:21 [my ssh user]@[my domain name].com
```

And it just hangs at "connecting" when I try to connect to

```
[my ftp user]@[my domain name].us:1234
```

with an FTP client.

I've tried using multiple SSH apps.

Can anyone give me any advice?

Comment: try the -v switch in ssh to see if the tunnel creation was successful

Comment: I know the tunnel creation was successful because my app tells me.

Comment: Off topic: belongs on superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Comment: @EJP The question is about using an Android client to connect to a particular service. It has nothing to do with the server or server configuration in any way. Why does it belong on either of those two?

Answer (score 1):

Once the tunnel is created, you should connect to mysql using `localhost:1234` or `127.0.0.1:1234`